# What is a "seized" power strip?

Tags: electrical

A power strip here could likely be replaced with surge protector.

But I have no idea what "seized" means.

Comment: We don’t either.  In what context?

Comment: Was it taken as evidence? Was it repossessed? Has its protection failed and it has stopped permitting current to flow? Has its oil leaked out and its moving parts have seized?

Answer (score 5):

That term is not a known term.  Literally, you are the only person on the known web to have ever used the expression.

[image]

Congratulations, I guess!

Comment: That's an accomplishment.  I was reading IT tickets at work and someone said that the problem was a seized powerstrip.